# Combining objects together in a one to many relationship

Tags: javascript, object

I have a piece of code which outputs multiple arrays of objects. How do I merge those objects together so I can get a combined object with a one to many relationship?

[Plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/yPZ4nTNbf09a5IROO55e?p=preview)

```
var newGender = { gender: "Male" };
var newFruit = [{ fruits: "Apple" }, { fruits: "Orange" }, { fruits: "Kiwi" } ];
var newName = "My name";
```

How do I write a function to combine these data together so I get a array like this?

```
[
    {
        gender: "Male",
        name: "My name",
        fruits: "Apple"
    },
    {
        gender: "Male",
        name: "My name",
        fruits: "Orange"
    },
    {
        gender: "Male",
        name: "My name",
        fruits: "Kiwi"
    }
]
```

Each entry in fruits I select should be a separate object.

Comment: That is too much code.  Could you delete all the angularjs and just leave the input and output needed to describe your question?  Your html is not relevant to lodash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since fruits are the only item for which multiple values can be selected, this is pretty simple:

```js
function combineSelections(name, gender, fruits) {
  if (!(name && gender && fruits)) {
    return [];
  }

  return fruits.map(function(fruit) {
    return {
      name: name,
      gender: gender.gender,
      fruit: fruit.fruits
    };
  });
}

var newName = 'Arun';
var newGender = {
  gender: 'male'
};
var newFruits = [
  { fruits: 'kiwi' },
  { fruits: 'dragonfruit' },
  { fruits: 'mango' }
];

console.log(combineSelections(newName, newGender, newFruits));
```